# Flask set form default values from database

Tags: flask

I'm trying a simple form in flask, here is the code:

```
class settingsForm(Form):
    def get_new_login_enable_sms():
        user = current_user
        print user.get_id()
        return True
    new_login_enable_sms = BooleanField('new_login_enable_sms',default=get_new_login_enable_sms())
```

What I want to do is that instead of return True or False by the functions, I want to get those values from the database, to do this, I need to check who is the current user, this class is defined in a separate file than the view and the flask method current_user doesn't work, and what I get is the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "views.py", line 9, in <module>
    from forms import *
  File "/home/taha/Desktop/rasberry_pi_project/Flask_rasberrypi_project/app/forms.py", line 15, in <module>
    class settingsForm(Form):
  File "/home/taha/Desktop/rasberry_pi_project/Flask_rasberrypi_project/app/forms.py", line 40, in settingsForm
    new_login_enable_sms              = BooleanField('new_login_enable_sms',default=get_new_login_enable_sms())
  File "/home/taha/Desktop/rasberry_pi_project/Flask_rasberrypi_project/app/forms.py", line 18, in get_new_login_enable_sms
    print user.get_id()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 343, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_id'
```

And here is my Loader function:

`@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(id):
        conn = sqlite3.connect('users.db')
        c=conn.cursor()
        # fetch user_name:
        query="SELECT user_name FROM user WHERE id = '"+id+"'"
        c.execute(query)
        user_name = c.fetchone()[0]
        # fetch is_authenticated:
        query="SELECT is_authenticated FROM user WHERE id = '"+id+"'"
        c.execute(query)
        is_authenticated = c.fetchone()[0]
        # fetch is_active:
        query="SELECT is_active FROM user WHERE id = '"+id+"'"
        c.execute(query)
        is_active = c.fetchone()[0]
        #close connection:
        conn.close()
        user= User(user_name,is_active,is_authenticated)
        return user`

Comment: Do you have `@login_manager.user_loader` in your code then show us ?

Comment: please delete this comment and update the question instead !

Comment: what is the form for?